# How to run flutter app without connecting usb in IOS Devices

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How to run flutter app without connecting usb in IOS Devices.

I can able to build Flutter Apps by using ADB Wi-Fi. And how i need to connect Flutter Apps in IOS Devices without connecting usb to pc, in Android Studio.

I didn’t find any sources to connect my iPhone 13 pro max to my pc without using USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

connect iPhone via usb

use an xcode feature to enable connect via network

disconnect iPhone

[image]

Run your app

Comment: I am trying to do this in same manner but it is not working.